# Mocha Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I tried to test a async function. But mocha always log timeout error.

```
// iframe.js
var iframe_client_util = {};
iframe_client_util.findByKeyFrame = function (keyFrame, cb) {
    ModelIframeClient.find({key_frame: keyFrame}).exec(function (err, rs) {
        if (err) return cb(err, null);

        cb(null, rs);
    });
};



// test.js
var assert = require("assert");
var iframe_util = require("./iframe");
describe('1. _checkAuthorization', function () {
    it("Using setTimeout to simulate asynchronous code!", function (done) {
        iframe_util.findByKeyFrame("598ad74b1ca8870b0072b6e9", function (err, result) {
            assert.equal(true, true);
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

Then mocha log this error when I run `mocha test.js`:

`Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.`

I follow this document: https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code.

Comment: The test seems to be taking over 2000ms. Perhaps test against a fake async function?

Comment: @evolutionxbox `iframe_util.findByKeyFrame` is "a fake async function" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem .  I didn't connect to mongoDB, iframe_util.findByKeyFrame function cannot run . It need mongoose.connect(); before describes.

Comment: If you delete your own answer here, you should be able then to delete your question. That's faster than asking the community "close this question".

Answer (score 0):

You can set the timeout in each test with `this.timeout(x);` or when you call mocha to specify the timeout with `mocha --timeout x`, where `x` is the timeout amount.

```
var assert = require("assert");
var iframe_util = require("./iframe");
describe('1. _checkAuthorization', function () {
    it("Using setTimeout to simulate asynchronous code!", function (done) {
        this.timeout(x); // x is timeout amount
        iframe_util.findByKeyFrame("598ad74b1ca8870b0072b6e9", function (err, result) {
            assert.equal(true, true);
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: when I set `this.timeout(3000);` It displayed `Error: timeout of 3000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.`. Just don't know why .

Comment: try with a bigger timeout

Comment: I tried with bigger timeout. But nothing changed.
`Error: timeout of 300000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.`

Comment: `iframe_util.findByKeyFrame` use mongoose . is it problem ?